# Callback for change() method which called an ajax

Tags: jquery

example of code with jQuery ALL THIS HTML PART IS LOADED via ajax too:

```html
<button> Lets Go </button>

<select id='first'>
    <option value='1'> 1 </option>
    <option value='2'> 2 </option>
    <option value='3'> 3 </option>
</select>

<select id='second'>
</select>

$('button').click(function(){
    $('#first option[value=1]').prop('selected',true);// WORK
    $('#first').change();     //   WORK
    $('#second option[value=1]').prop('selected',true);// this DONT WORK
    $('#second').change();
});
```

The problem is here, it tries to select option but the data is not loaded yet via ajax so it doesn't have what to select. How can I use call back on `$('#first').change();` to waiting for data load and after go next?

```js
$('body').on('change','#first',function(){
    // on "#first" change the "#second" select automaticaly filled with code via ajax;
```

so will be now like

```html
<select id='second'>
    <option value='1'> 1 </option>
    <option value='2'> 2 </option>
    <option value='3'> 3 </option>
</select>

})

$('body').on('change','#second',function(){
   //   console.log() doesn't see the selected value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you've assigned a change event listener to the first select element whose handler performs an AJAX request. AJAX requests being inherently Asynchronous means that code which depends on the result of the AJAX request must wait until the request completes.

So, you've got something like this: (not really, but this is a working example that makes a bit more sense)

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const simulHTML = v => `<div class="example">Example #${v}</div>`;
const simulAJAX = v => new Promise(r => setTimeout(_ => r(simulHTML(v)), 400));

$(select).change(async e => wrapper.innerHTML = await simulAJAX(e.target.value));
$(button).click(e => {
  select.value = "1";
  $(select).change();
  console.log(wrapper.innerHTML); // ""
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option disabled selected>---
  <option value="1">1
  <option value="2">2
  <option value="3">3
</select>
<button>button</button>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Once it comes time to work with the HTML inserted by the AJAX callback, we see that the result hasn't arrived yet.

Now, there are a few ways to deal with this ranging from quick and dirty (and unsafe) to the more complex (but safer). Here's a middle ground, and what I would generally choose.

First, an IIFE to keep the logic safe from the rest of the page. In this we will define a `Set` to hold listeners, enclose the definition of our change listener, execute the listeners once the AJAX request has completed, and finally provide a mechanism for adding and removing listeners.

```
const listen = (_ => {
  const listeners = new Set();

  $(select).change(async e => {
    wrapper.innerHTML = await simulAJAX(e.target.value);
    listeners.forEach(e => e());
  });

  return {
    add: (...args) => listeners.add.bind(listeners)(...args),
    delete: (...args) => listeners.delete.bind(listeners)(...args)
  }
})();
```

Next, to use what we just made, simply use the `add` and `delete` methods of the new `listen` object.

```
const listener = _ => {
    console.log(wrapper.innerHTML);
    listen.delete(listener); // remove after
}
listen.add(listener);
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const simulHTML = v => `<div class="example">Example #${v}</div>`;
const simulAJAX = v => new Promise(r => setTimeout(_ => r(simulHTML(v)), 400));

const listen = (_ => {
  const listeners = new Set();
  
  $(select).change(async e => {
    wrapper.innerHTML = await simulAJAX(e.target.value);
    listeners.forEach(e => e());
  });
  
  return {
    add: (...args) => listeners.add.bind(listeners)(...args),
    delete: (...args) => listeners.delete.bind(listeners)(...args)
  }
})();

$(button).click(e => {
  select.value = "1";
  $('select').change();
  
  const listener = _ => {
    console.log(wrapper.innerHTML);
    listen.delete(listener); // remove after
  }
  
  listen.add(listener);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option disabled selected>---
  <option value="1">1
  <option value="2">2
  <option value="3">3
</select>
<button>button</button>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: thank you a lot but it is complicated for me i will try to implement it on my side to check how it work!

Comment: 1 of the solution that i find and it work!

`setTimeout( function() {
        $('#second option[value=1]').prop('selected',true); 
        $('#second').change();
        },300); `

so it wait 0.3 sec and after  select the option from second select!! but if the internet connection is low ? and it take more than 0.3 sec to ready ajax will fire error again! ..

Comment: @Onferflay thats a horrible hackish way to go about it, but sure. I thought you wanted a solution, not a dirty hack.

Comment: must i be more skilled to understand your code i am begginer  yet! just try to make it work no matter how...